# query to fetch users who ordered a particular item more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have 2 tables, users and orders
**users: user_id, name
orders: order_id, user_id(foreign key users), item_name, price**

want to fetch the **user_ids** for which **item_name** 'apple' and 'mangoes' has been ordered more than once.

**users**

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | XYZ |

**orders**

| order_id | user_id | item_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | apple | 12 |
| 2 | 2 | pears | 11 |
| 3 | 1 | apple | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | mango | 22 |
| 5 | 2 | banana | 13 |
| 6 | 2 | apple | 13 |
| 7 | 1 | mango | 13 |
| 8 | 1 | apple | 13 |
| 9 | 2 | cherry | 13 |
| 10 | 1 | berry | 13 |
| 11 | 1 | apple | 13 |

Comment: Do you want those users that ordered both products more than one or at least one of them more than once?

Comment: at least any of them more than once

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ORDERS (order_id,  user_id ,   item_name,  price)AS
(
   SELECT   1,  1,  'apple',    12 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    2,  'pears',    11 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 ,   1,  'apple',    2 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    1 , 'mango' ,   22 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    2 , 'banana',   13 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 ,   2,  'apple',    13 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 ,   1,  'mango' ,   13 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    1,  'apple',    13 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 ,   2 , 'cherry',   13 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    1 , 'berry' ,   13 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    1,  'apple' ,   13
)
SELECT C.user_id
FROM ORDERS AS C
WHERE C.item_name='mango' OR C.item_name='apple'
GROUP BY C.user_id
HAVING COUNT(C.order_id)>1
```

Can not be sure, but may be you need something like this

Comment: this won't work. c.order_id will return greater than 1 when user ordered both(once each)

Comment: I have another option SELECT C.user_id
FROM ORDERS AS C
WHERE C.item_name='mango' 
INTERSECT
SELECT C.user_id
FROM ORDERS AS C
WHERE C.item_name='apple'